# How to use IntelliJ IDEA 14 for development of OSGi application that's build with Maven and Tycho?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, osgi, tycho

Eclipse RCP application is running with OSGi. It uses manifest-first approach and built using Maven and Tycho. Is there a way to switch from Eclipse PDE to IntelliJ IDEA 14?

Answer (score 2):

No. You should give up manifest-first anyway, it's bad for you.

Comment: Why it is bad? Please elaborate more.

Comment: It makes sense when you are using RCP and p2.

Comment: @Neil so it should be used pom first approach ?

Comment: I prefer not to call it "POM first" because that assumes Maven. I call it "generated manifest". Manifest-first is a bad idea, and anyway it only works in Eclipse PDE.